# How can I force the "Required32bit" PEKind flag?

Tags: c#

I am developping an application relying on a library that does a hard check on the "Required32bit" flag:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
PortableExecutableKinds peKind;
ImageFileMachine machine;
assembly.ManifestModule.GetPEKind(out peKind, out machine);
if ((peKind & PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit) != PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit)
    throw new Exception(Resources.WrongArchitecture);
}
```

I need my application to have the `Required32Bit` flag, in order to be able to use the library.

I have set the platform solution to `x86` in the configuration manager and set `<Platforms>x86</Platforms>` in the .csproj, but this results in the `Preferred32Bit` flag.

How can I force the "Required32bit" PEKind flag?